# Control Two HTML Tables With One Scroll Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, scrollbar

I have two separate tables of hopefully same height side by side. I want to be able to have the two communicate with each other so that when I scroll the right table down, the left table will also scroll with it in sync.

As of now, the only way I could think of doing this is by enclosing both of them in a div, but this messes with my sizing settings when I try so. Is there a better way of having the two tables communicate and scroll up and down at the same time?

HTML:

```
<!-- Scrollable y-axis line of days above the scheduler -->
  <div id="table-wrapper-days">
    <div id="table-scroll-days">
      <table id="dayRow" class="tableDays">
        <tr>
          <td>Monday 5/7</td>
          <td>Tuesday 5/8</td>
          <td>Wednesday 5/9</td>
          <td>Thursday 5/10</td>
          <td>Friday 5/11</td>
          <td>Saturday 5/12</td>
          <td>Sunday 5/13</td>
          <td>Monday 5/14</td>
          <td>Tuesday 5/15</td>
          <td>Wednesday 5/16</td>
          <td>Thursday 5/17</td>
          <td>Friday 5/18</td>
          <td>Saturday 5/19</td>
          <td>Sunday 5/20</td>
          <td>Monday 5/21</td>
          <td>Tuesday 5/22</td>
          <td>Wednesday 5/23</td>
          <td>Thursday 5/24</td>
          <td>Friday 5/25</td>
          <td>Saturday 5/26</td>
          <td>Sunday 5/27</td>
          <td>Monday 5/28</td>
          <td>Tuesday 5/29</td>
          <td>Wednesday 5/30</td>
          <td>Thursday 5/31</td>
          <td>Friday 6/1</td>
          <td>Saturday 6/2</td>
          <td>Sunday 6/3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Scrollable x-axis column of employees to the left of the scheduler -->
  <div id="table-wrapper-employees">
    <div id="table-scroll-employees">
      <table id="employeeCol" class="tableEmployees">
        <tr><td>Employee A</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee B</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee C</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee D</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee E</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee F</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee G</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee H</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee I</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee J</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee K</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee L</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee M</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee N</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee O</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee P</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee Q</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee R</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee S</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee T</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee U</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee V</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee W</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee X</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee Y</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee Z</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="table-wrapper-tasks">
  <div id="table-scroll-tasks">
    <script>
      var rows = document.getElementById('dayRow').getElementsByTagName("td").length;
      var cols = document.getElementById('employeeCol').getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
      var rowT = null;

      var drawTable = '<table class="tableTasks">';
        for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
          drawTable += '<tr>';
          for(let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            drawTable += '<td></td>';
          }
          drawTable += '</tr>';
        }
        drawTable += '</table>';

        document.write(drawTable);
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* To control the style of the overall table class */
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 140px;
  height: 35px;
}

/* Settings for Days row */
.tableDays {
  width: 140px;
}

/* Settings for Employee column */
.tableEmployees {
  line-height: 35px;
}

/* Settings for Tasks table */
.tableTasks {
  width:100%;
  margin-top:5px;
  empty-cells: show;
  height:1000px;
  line-height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
}

.empTaskCont {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#table-wrapper-days {
  position: relative;
  width:1064px;
  margin-left: 252px
}

#table-scroll-days {
  height: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#table-wrapper-employees {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  width:18%;
  margin-top:8px;
}

#table-scroll-employees {
  width: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 500px;
}

#table-wrapper-tasks {
  position: relative;
  width:81%;
  float:right;
}

#table-scroll-tasks {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 522px;
}

.employee-mod-btn{
  float:left;
}
```

I included a jsfiddle for my code: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqzyw4u4/6/#&togetherjs=5vkFrp9DEa

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you add a js fiddle, it will be easier for debugging and giving the answer.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqzyw4u4/6/#&togetherjs=5vkFrp9DEa

Comment: Hmm why don't you fix your sizing settings? If you want to do in separate divs, you will have to use javascript on scroll event, if you can do it in single div and fix the sizing settings, you don't need javascript.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that, thank you. I'm really new to HTML so everything is learn as I go at this point. I'm sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: Something very different, so I understand if this is completely different from what you want but what about this? One table with the necessary sizing? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uj6vhnm3/1/). I used [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables#) tables generator for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's how you can do it with javascript if you need the tables in two separate containers:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqzyw4u4/7/

Just using onscroll event, getting the scroll position and setting it to the other container.

```
  function scrollPos(){
    var rightScrollPos = document.getElementById("table-scroll-tasks").scrollTop;

    document.getElementById("table-scroll-employees").scrollTop = rightScrollPos;
```

}

```
  <div id="table-scroll-tasks" onscroll="scrollPos();">
```

Comment: Thanks Dzhambazov.. great fiddle.. most helpful :+1 In my case of horizontal scroll the key was to synchronize on the scrollLeft property of the scrolling divs.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Question looking for something similar, but I have a piece of code to sync horizontal scrolls using jQuery.

```
function syncScrolls() {
    let div1 = $('#id_div1');
    let div2 = $("#id_div2");

    div1.scroll(function () {
        div2.scrollTop(div1.scrollTop());
        div2.scrollLeft(div1.scrollLeft());
    });
    div2.scroll(function () {
        div1.scrollTop(div2.scrollTop());
        div1.scrollLeft(div2.scrollLeft());
    });
}
```